# If else condition precedence in Verilog

Tags: if-statement, verilog, system-verilog

I have noticed that there is a precedence of assignment while using if-else conditionals in Verilog. For example as in the code below:

```
if(counter < 6)
  z <= 1;
else if(counter < 12)
  z <= 2;
else
  z <= 3;
```

I noticed that until the counter is less than 6, the value of `z` is assigned the value of 1 (`z <= 1`) and as soon as the value of the counter exceeds 6 and is less than 12, `z` is assigned the value 2 (`z <= 2`).

What if there are different variables used inside the conditionals as in the code below?

```
if(wire1_is_enabled)
  z <= 1;
else if(wire2_is_enabled)
  z <= 0;
```

What happens when both conditions are true? What is the behaviour of the assignment operator here?
I believe this is poor programming habit.

Comment: If both `wire1_is_enabled` and `wire2_is_enabled`  are `true` then `z <= 1` will trigger. If you use `if` in both instead of `else if` then `z <= 0` will trigger this is because `if` conditions trigger one after another here `z <=0` is the latest one hence at the end `z` will settle to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 `if/else` statements behave the same way; the first condition to be true has the highest priority.  Once a condition evaluates to true, all the following `else` clauses are ignored.  Therefore, `z <= 1` if both `wire1_is_enabled` and `wire2_is_enabled` are true.  This is easy to prove to yourself with a simple simulation.

This is not a poor coding habit.  This situation is common in Verilog.  When you say `programming`, perhaps you are thinking of software languages.  Keep in mind that these are hardware signals instead of software variables.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, nested `if-else` branching statements naturally assume a priority in the order of execution. Think about using a `case` statement instead of deeply nesting `if` statements which are much more readable.

There is nothing wrong with this coding style unless you have code like:

```
if(counter < 6)
  z <= 1;
else if(counter < 2)
  z <= 2; // unreachable
else
  z <= 3;
```

Then the statement `z <= 2;` becomes *unreachable* because when the first condition is false, the second condition can never be true. Fortunately there are a number of tools that can flag this problem for you.

Both `if` and `case` statements assume priority logic. However, you have an option to explicitly add a `priority` or `unique` keyword before the `if` or `case` keywords to declare and check your intent. See sections 12.4 and 12.5 in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).